# MainActivity.java issue starting a new Android Project

Tags: android

When I start a new android project in eclipse there is an error inside which I can't fix, even with the hint. How is it possibile?
I work with Mint 64bit and Eclipse 64bit, I followed the tutorial on the ufficial page to install all I need. This is the code. The problem is in setContentView and in getMenuInflater with R class. I don't know what to do, I can't find a solution on internet...

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the text of the error message?

Comment: I must implement the R class. I import the library, but then I must change activity_main, I change it, but then it says me that there's an incorect paramenter in the function setContentView

Comment: Probably you don't import R class. Try adding `import com.example.myfirstapp.R`

Answer (score 0):

R class is created in build time. The problem may be that the project hadn'y built. In this case, you should build (or rebuild) your project.
In eclipse you can select Project->Build automatically so the compiler will build your project automatically.

Comment: can you see the class R in the package explorer? (under my first app->gen->com.example.myfirstapp->R)

Comment: Nope, there's just BuildConfig.java

Comment: @Amk This is the problem. The class R supposed to be created. Try project->clean... and select clean all and press OK.

Comment: I tryed, but nothing. I have the code of the R.java, can I create the class manually and copy the code in there?

Comment: Create the class manually is bad idea, becouse it don't really solve the problem, but just hide it.  In [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543450/disappearance-of-r-java-file) question, the third answer could be usefull for you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't import R class. Try adding:

```
import com.example.myfirstapp.R
```

Comment: I do, but then I must change activity_main in inflate function, but it gives me another error and no suggestions on how to repair it...

Comment: You shouldn't have to change activity_main in inflate function. Please add the XML file where you define activity_main, probably there's a problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you are running on a 64 bit system, ensure that 32 bit libraries are installed. Run sudo apt-get install ia32-libs. Restart eclipse/ADT.